# How do i put multiple images in an external CSS

Tags: css

Apologies if this has been answered but i cannot find it anywhere on here or the web.

Is it possible to put multiple images inside an external css file? I have the background in there and it displays correctly. I can't get the other images to show though as i'm unsure which tags to use (html dont work in an external css)

Comment: What does mean put multiple images inside external css file ?

Comment: I wish to have the background image as an external CSS file, and in that same CSS i also wish to have other images displayed on the web page

Comment: Inigo Montoya comes to mind, @MonkeyBoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing external images in CSS works like so:

```
#foo{ background-image: url(path/to/image.jpg); }

#bar{ background-image: url(path/to/anotherimage.jpg); }
```

As you can see abovve, any element can reference an image, per CSS declaration.

Be aware that the path you reference in your CSS file is relative to the CSS file location, not the HTML. For example, if your directory structure looks like this:

```
index.html
/img
    - banner.jpg
    - logo.png
/css
    - styles.css
```

adding the banner to a given #foo element in your CSS file would look like this:

```
#foo{ background-image: url(../img/banner.jpg) }
```

Notice the ../ - that translates into "go up one directory".

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I have all my CSS files in the root folder for the webpage (not root folder of pc) and the images are in an image folder.

Comment: In your case, background declarations would look like this: #foo{ backgound-image: url(imageFolder/imageName.extension) }